# Asp.Net Membership with ActiveDirectoryMembership Provider

Tags: asp.net, active-directory, asp.net-membership

We're having speed problems still with the login control and the Ad membership provider.

We've tracked it down to a specific issue, when initally trying to connect for the first time, it sends this SAM LOGON message:

117 10.717526 10.140.4.84 10.140.4.223 SMB_NETLOGON SAM LOGON request from client

It Gets sent 4 seperate time on udp port 138 trying to connect to our AD server.

This takes over 30 seconds, the vast majority of our login times.

Is there any way to configure the Ad Membership Privder to not attempt to udp on this port/SAM LOGON,and just skip that step?

or does anyone know what needs to be altered on the server to make it respons to this request?

There was no firewall or anything like that between the machines. They were on the same switch.

Thanks,

Comment: if this is an internal only app have you considered using Integrated Windows Authentication

Comment: It's not internal only alas, it's public facing and internal apps both.
Thanks,
E-

Answer (score 0, accepted):

adServer was notaccepting connections on 636 so we had to set connectionprotection = none.
it was not documetned anywhere, but I had to put ad\ in front of the username
or connection proteciton=none threw errors.

Once that was fixed the communication was only on 385 and login was very fast.

E-